# Create multiple buttons React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, chakra-ui

I have the ability to render my single button with all my options inside of the one button like this:
[image]

What I want to do is separate these into individual buttons

My code is as follows (the first button is the one in question, how do I make them individual?)

```
function Filters({ filter, setFilter, location }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-transparent outline-none text-sm text-gray-600 placeholder-grey-400">
      <div className="pl-2 pr-2 gap-3">
        <Button
          colorScheme="teal"
          size="xs"
          onClick={(e) => {
            setFilter({
              ...filter,
              search: e.target.value,
            });
          }}
        >
          {locations.map((item, index) => (
            <text>
              <option key={index} value={item.location}>
                {item.location}
              </option>
            </text>
          ))}
        </Button>
        <Button
          colorScheme="teal"
          size="xs"
          onClick={(e) => {
            setFilter({
              ...filter,
              search: e.target.value,
            });
          }}
        >
          ALL
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Filters;
```

Comment: Put the button tag inside the map loop

Comment: Why do you have an `<option>` tag inside a button? Option is only used inside `select`, `optgtroup` and `datalist`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option